# VBA excel - Calling a function from excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA program to remove vowels. I am not able to call the function from excel. i get a #NAME error. Code  below

```
Function REMOVEVOWELS(Txt) As String
'Removes all vowels from the Txt argument
 Dim i As Long
 REMOVEVOWELS = ""
 For i = 1 To Len(Txt)
     If Not UCase(Mid(Txt, i, 1)) Like "(AEIOU)" Then
         REMOVEVOWELS = REMOVEVOWELS & Mid(Txt, i, 1)
     End If
 Next i
 End Function
```

Code tags inserted by Tim Stack

Comment: It does work as in it doesn't give a `#Name` error.  It doesn't take out the vowels either though.

Answer (score 2):

Rewritten, tested, and works! Insert this at the top of a Module

```
Function REMOVEVOWELS(Txt) As String
'Removes all vowels from the Txt argument
 Dim i As Long
 For i = 1 To Len(Txt)
    If Mid(Txt, i, 1) Like "[AEIOU]" Then
        Txt = Replace(Txt, Mid(Txt, i, 1), "")
    End If
 Next i
REMOVEVOWELS = Txt
 End Function
```

EDIT

A more elegant solution.

```
Function REMOVEVOWELS(Txt) As String
'Removes all vowels from the Txt argument
Vowels = Array("A", "E", "I", "O", "U")

For Each a In Vowels
    Txt = Replace(Txt, a, "")
Next a
REMOVEVOWELS = Txt
 End Function
```

Comment: Now that I think of it... Perhaps you are better off just adding a Replace function for each of the 5 vowels instead of looping through all characters in the string. What my code does now is replacing all of one vowel in the string anyway once it finds said vowel. Running the Replace function five times should not put a lot of strain on Excel

Comment: I hadn't spotted the square bracket mistake. So the original code posted by OP does work if he uses `[]` instead of `()` and puts the code in the correct place.  But, as you say - `REPLACE` would be simpler.

Comment: That's right, I have added a more elegant solution that does not require the function to loop through all characters

Comment: Dr Mr Bartrup-Cook and Mr Stack. I copied your code and also inserted Square brackets to specify ranges. I have also placed this code in a new VBA module, I am still getting a #NAME error.

Comment: Are you pasting the code in the same workbook as the one you're using the formula in? What kind of strings are you adding to the formula?

Comment: Yes I have and the #NAME error doesn't appear. But I am not seeing the text without vowels. I used the code you had suggested. Another question is if the source text is in C2 for instance, =REMOVEVOWELS(c2) pasted in E2 should do the trick, right?

Comment: The example you provided specifies the function should only remove capitalised vowels. If you want all vowels removed, add them to the array in my code

Comment: Replace Code is excellent.Thanks.  Just one question. You have mentioned "For Each a", in this example a is a pointer to a location? plus I can't use another Pointer such as x?

Comment: `a` refers to the item in the array. Can be named anything sensible

Answer (score 1):

Regardign the #NAME error (not about the logic) - most likely you've added function at Application of Sheet level in VBA. It must be added in separate module instead (Right click on VBAProject - Insert - Module)